# Finding files dynamically

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, filewriter

I want to be able to repeat an action for every file in a directory.

This is my current code

```
File file = new File("res\\thing.csv");
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    Dat = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    try {
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            for(String s : values) {
                Dat.add(s);
                //System.out.println(String.valueOf(Dat));
            }
        }
    }
catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It then goes on to change the extracted variables before writing to a new file. How can I get this program to automatically do this for every file in a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File dir = new File("directoryName");
if(dir.isDirectory())
{
    File filesList[] = dir.listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < filesList.length; i++)
    {
        //do your processing here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over values returned by [File.listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) call where File representing your directory

Answer (score 0):

```
File directory = new File("/your/directory/path");

for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
  //do something with file
}
```